# Express not sending secure cookie session on distant server with HTTPS

Tags: express, cookies, express-session

Express is not sending any Set-Cookie header with express-session while the option *secure* is set to *true*.
I am doing this on a distant server with a valid certificate signed with Let's Encrypt.

```
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

const sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    rolling: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: false,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10 * 1000
    }
});

app.use(sessionMiddleware)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    req.session.foo = 'bar';
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

How can I get Express to set the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Express is served behind a reverse proxy.

I had to specify the following header to Apache:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```